# How to define a callable that can only be called once?

Tags: python

To demonstrate what I want to do, here's a piece of code:

```
class CallOnce(object):
    called=False
    def web_service(cls,macid):
        if cls.called:
            print ("already called")
            return
        else:
            # do stuff
            print ("called once")
            cls.called = True
            return macid
```

To test our class, I proceed as follows:

```
for i in range(2):

    macid = "123"
    call_once_object = CallOnce()
    call = call_once_object.web_service(macid)
    print(call)
```

The expected result should be like this:

```
called once
123
already called
```

Except I got this as a result:

```
called once
123
called once
123
```

The idea is to store the value `123` only once in the call variable without using global variable.

Comment: A typo, sorry. I just edited

Comment: in every loop you create new instance `CallOnce` so it doesn't remeber previous instance. You would need class property

Comment: Should each instance of the class only be called once? Or can you have many instances, and only one method call globally? Also, should you guard against more instances being created?

Comment: Thanks @catleeball, The problem is fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cls.called` is an attribute of the instance, not the class. Each time you create a new object, it gets its own attribute, which defaults to `False`.

If you want to share this among all the instances, you should use `CallOnce.called`, not `cls.called`.

BTW, the conventional name for the first argument of instance methods is `self`. `cls` is used for class methods.

Answer (score 4):

So you're trying to save some state. What you could do is use an object instead.

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.called = False

    def call_me_maybe(self):
        if (not self.called):
            print('Hey, you called?')
            self.called = True
        else:
            print("Stop calling me it's getting weird")

test = Test()
test.call_me_maybe() #-> Hey, you called?
test.call_me_maybe() #-> Stop calling me it's getting weird
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a class for this. Functions can have their own attributes.

```
def web_service(macid):
    if hasattr(web_service, 'called'):
        print ("already called")
        return
    else:
        # do stuff
        print ("called once")
        web_service.called = True
        return macid

web_service(5)
web_service(6)
```

Output:

```
called once
already called
```